# Nim: On mac, cannot open standard import

Tags: nim-lang

I'm using nim on Mac, and am having trouble with this line:

```
from strutils import parseInt
```

It gives this error when trying to compile:

csvx.nim(1, 6) Error: cannot open 'strutils'
~/dev/polyglot/csvx/

I installed nim using the "Installation based on generated C code" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by following the "Installation from github" installation option, basically building nim from scratch.

I should note, too, that I created an alias for "nim" that pointed to the build location. Moving the nim executable into my /usr/local/bin caused problems.